# Finite and infinite primes of a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. How to find the finite primes of a number field. can any one give some illustrations.

Comment: You mean the non-archimedean absolute values? They are just the absolute values corresponding to the primes of $\mathcal{O}_K$. What more were you looking for?

Comment: Also, the infinite primes are just the $r+s$ absolute values endowed on $K$ from the $r$ real and $s$ pairs of complex emebeddings $K\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$. This is known as the Ostrowski Theorem for Number Fields in some circles--such as my own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I said, finding the absolute values for a number field corresponds to finding the primes for the corresponding number rings, and the embeddings of the number field into $\mathbb{C}$.

You can find a proof of that [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/ostrowski.pdf).

Finding all of them explicitly is a pain, and even when you can describe them all explicitly, it's not in a very enlightening form. Let me illustrate

For example, take $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

To find the Archimedean absolute values, we find the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$. They are, in particular $\sigma,\overline{\sigma}$ where $\sigma(a+bi)=a+bi$. In particular, define 
$$|a+bi|_\infty=|\sigma(a+bi)|=|\overline{\sigma}(a+bi)|$$
 where the absolute value on the RHS is the normal absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$. Then, $|\cdot|_\infty$ is the only infinite place of $K$.

To find the finite places, we need to find the primes of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. To do this, we use the Dedekind-Kummer theorem. Namely, let $p$ be a prime. Then, the primes above $p$ are $(p,g(i))$ where $g(x)$ is an irreducible factor of $x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ (or, more appropriately, a lift of such a factor). But, we know that in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

$$x^2+1=\begin{cases}(x+1)^2 & \mbox{if}\quad p=2\\ \left(x+\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{4}}\right)\left(x-\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{4}}\right) & \mbox{if}\quad p\equiv 1\mod 4\\ x^2+1 & \mbox{if}\quad p\equiv 3\mod 4\end{cases}$$

Where $\alpha$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. Thus, the primes of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are

$$P=\{(i+1)\}\cup\left\{\left(p,\pm\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{4}}\right):p\equiv 1\mod 4\text{ and }\alpha\text{ is a primitive root modulo }p\right\}\cup\{(p):p\equiv 3\mod 4\}$$

To each prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in this list, we can associate a valuation $v_\mathfrak{p}$ by defining $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)=m$ if $x\ne 0$ and

$$(x)=\mathfrak{p}^m\cdot(\text{other primes besides }\mathfrak{p})$$

We can then extend this to a valution on all of $K$ in the natural way. This then induces an absolute value $|\cdot|_\mathfrak{p}$ in the usual way.

Thus, the Ostrowski theorem for number fields tells us that the places on $K$ are merely $|\cdot|_\infty$ and $|\cdot|_\mathfrak{p}$ for $\mathfrak{p}$ in $S$, and that this list is not redundant.

Not any more satisfying than just the statement of Ostrowski, is it?

Comment: Thank you very much Alex Youcis, for the wonderful explanation, and Ostrowski's notes by Conrad.

Comment: @SushmaShenoy If you found my answer helpful, you can upvote/accept it :) This saves people the trouble of looking here since you've already found an acceptable answer.

Comment: @ Alex Youcis How to find more than one infinite place of a number field $K$ when do the exist

Comment: @SushmaShenoy There are only $r+s$ of them, where $r$ is the number of real embeddings of the number field into $\mathbb{C}$ and $s$ the number of pairs. So, for example, take $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$. There are $4$ embeddings, all non-real, and so two up to conjugation. Namely, up to conjugation there is only $\sigma_{\pm}$ with $\sigma_{\pm}(i)=i$ and $\sigma_{\pm}(\sqrt{2})=\pm\sqrt{2}$. Thus, the infinite places are just $|\cdot|_\pm$ with $|x|_\pm:=|\sigma_\pm(x)|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.